# Random list, SecretPhrase Java Project

Tags: java

My school project requires me to modify my last assignment (code below) to pull a random phrase from a list of at least 10 for the user to guess. I drawing a blank on this. Any help would be appreciated. I understand I have to add a class that would import the text file or list, then I would need to modify a loop in order for it to randomly select?

```
    import java.util.Scanner; // Allows the user to read different value types

    public class SecretPhrase {

    String phrase; //
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    SecretPhrase(String phrase){
        this.phrase = phrase.toLowerCase();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        SecretPhrase start = new SecretPhrase("Java is Great"); // The phrase the user will have identify
        start.go(); // Starts Program

    }

    void go(){
        String guess;
        String word="";
        String[] words = new String[phrase.length()]; // array to store all charachters
        ArrayList<String> lettersGuessed = new ArrayList();


         for(int i=0;i<phrase.length();i++){ 
            if(phrase.charAt(i)== ' '){words[i] = " ";} 
            else{words[i] = "*";} // Array that uses * to hide actual letters
        }

        int Gcount =0; // Records the count     
        while(!word.equals(phrase)){ // continues the loop
            word = "";
            int Lcount = 0;
            System.out.print("Guess a letter> ");
            guess = scan.next();


            for(int i=0;i<phrase.length();i++){ // Accounts for any attempts by user to use more than one charachter at a time.
                if((guess.charAt(0)+"").equals(phrase.charAt(i)+"")&&(lettersGuessed.indexOf(guess.charAt(0)+"")==-1)){

                    words[i] = ( guess.charAt(0))+ ""; 
                    Lcount++; 
                }
            }
            lettersGuessed.add(guess.charAt(0)+""); // Reveals the letter in phrase
            System.out.println("You found " + Lcount +" letters"); // Prints out the total number of times the charachter was in the phrase

            for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++){
                word=word+words[i]; 
            }
            System.out.println(word);
            Gcount ++;
        }
        System.out.println("Good Job! It took you " + Gcount + " guesses!" ); // Prints out result with total count

    }
}
```

Comment: First of all you have to try something.

Answer (score 0):

In the existing code, you are creating a SecretPhrase object with the phrase to guess:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    SecretPhrase start = new SecretPhrase("Java is Great");
    start.go(); // Starts Program

}
```

You should replace it with a List (either ArrayList or LinkedList would be fine) and populate it with your data (given by either file, user input or hard-coded):

```
ArrayList<SecretPhrase> phrases = new ArrayList<SecretPhrase>();
//reading from file:
File file = new File("myPhrases.txt");
FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
String phrase = null;
while ((phrase = br.readLine()) != null) {
    phrases.add(new SecretPhrase(phrase));
}
```

Now either use Random on phrases.size() and execute go on it, or if you're looking for it to be a series of phrases, you can create a permutation and loop over them. I'm not sure what your requirements here are.

Comment: Why use ancient APIs? If you are answering questions, please use appropriate code. This, is, in fact `List<SecretPhrase> phrases = Files.lines(Paths.get("myPhrases.txt")).map(SecretPhrase::new).collect(toList())`.